# Creating Jquery Horizontal menu Tabs with dynamic data

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build this code dynamically responsible for creating Jquery Horizontal Tabbed menu .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Three</a></li>
  </ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
  </div> 
  <div id="tabs-2">
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
     </div>
</div>

</div>
```

I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var categories= '{"categories":[{"name":"One"},{"name":"Two"},{"name":"Three"},{"name":"Four"},{"name":"Five"},{"name":"Six"},{"name":"Seven"}]}'; 
createhorizontaltab(categories);
$("#tabs").tabs();
});

function createhorizontaltab(categories) {
var categoryArr = JSON.parse(categories);
var htmlbuild =('<ul>');
for(var i=0;i<categoryArr.categories.length;i++)
{
 var name = categoryArr.categories[i].name;
 htmlbuild.append('<li><a href="'+name+'">'+name+'</a></li>');
htmlbuild.append('<div id="'+name+'"/>');
}
 htmlbuild.append('</ul>');

$("#tabs").append(htmlbuild);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="tabs">
</div>
```

But i am getting Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at the line

```
<li><a href="'+name+'">'+name+'</a></li>
```

Could anybody please tell me what causing the error .why its not building the tabs ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var categories = '{"categories":[{"name":"One"},{"name":"Two"},{"name":"Three"},{"name":"Four"},{"name":"Five"},{"name":"Six"},{"name":"Seven"}]}';
    createhorizontaltab(categories);
    $("#tabs").tabs({});
});

function createhorizontaltab(categories) {
    var categoryArr = JSON.parse(categories);
    var htmlbuild = $('<ul>');
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryArr.categories.length; i++) {
        var name = categoryArr.categories[i].name;
        htmlbuild.append('<li><a href="' + name + '">' + name + '</a></li>');
        htmlbuild.append('<div id="' + name + '"/>');
    }
    htmlbuild.append('</ul>');

    $("#tabs").append(htmlbuild);
}
```

Comment: When i ran the above code and clicked on each generated tab ,its generating net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  in console .how to solve that

Comment: Please check at - <a href = "name" . Probably it should be replaced with some link? http://yourwebiste.com/cat.aspx?name=' + name ?

Comment: When the href is clicked on it should open up the div thats all .so i guess i should use <a href="#' + name to refer to the div .

Comment: Yes in that case # should do the job.

Comment: htmlbuild.append('<div id="#' + name + '"/>');

Comment: Should i use <a href="#'+ name + '">'+name+'</a></li> ?? to refer to the div ??

Comment: Thank you very much , I have written the folloing http://jsfiddle.net/3Yy3t/ ,  how to know what is efficient ??

Comment: @user3674364 it comes down to your UI design how it will make an impact to it. You could achieve the result with one for loop; I thought gave you a direction to proceed further. Now your base problem is fixed. 

Next task for you could be to - catch click and get data from the server through AJAX. Please refer here: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

If I could help you, please mark it answered.

Comment: I will stick to your code , Correct my next task is i should capture the clciked div and call backend . $("#tabs").click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});  but i dont know why the alert is not being fired up , any clue /?

Comment: use $("tabs")tabs({
  select: function(event, ui){
     // You need Firebug or the developer tools on your browser open to see these
        console.log(event);
        // This will get you the index of the tab you selected
        console.log(event.options.selected);
        // And this will get you it's name
        console.log(event.tab.text);
  }

Comment: this is not working $("tabs")tabs({ select: function(event, ui){

Comment: $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
             var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
            alert(active);
        }
    });

Comment: How did you go .. You may accept the answer. If solved

Comment: Don't mind , but can i get the name , instead of number in the alert ??

Comment: var selected = $("#tabs").tabs( "option", "selected" );
var selectedTabTitle = $($("#tabs ul")[selected]).text();

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should do this

```
var htmlbuild =$('<ul>');
```

I think you just missed $ there.

Comment: Correct , i missed that , but when i click on each generated tab , its throwing me , net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in console .